# How to run Mason (HTML-Mason) on IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, perl

I have a website using Mason that I must transfer to an IIS7 server.

I followed the instructions here http://www.masonhq.com/?RunningMasonUnderIIS, but they seem specific for IIS 6 and I have trouble understanding how to apply them to IIS 7. 
In the end, the site is giving me the error "The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are "Can't locate object method "new" via package "HTML::Mason::Parser" (perhaps you forgot to load "HTML::Mason::Parser"?) at c:\atm\cgi_handler.pl line 31."

I installed HTML-Mason version 1.48 via Perl Package Manager version 4.14
Perl has been installed with ActivePerl version 5.14.2.1402

Anyone has experience making Mason work on IIS 7?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

HTML::Mason::Parser is no longer part of HTML::Mason so would need to be installed and use'd in addition to HTML::Mason if you absolutely had to use it, but note that Parser has been superseded by Lexer and Compiler.